# Creating reusable scaffolders

Tags: powershell, t4, t4scaffolding

I followed the instructions on [creating a custom scaffolder](http://average-uffe.blogspot.ca/2011/06/basics-in-t4scaffolding-in-visual.html) using the [T4 Scaffolding](http://nuget.org/packages/T4Scaffolding) package and they worked great. However, in the process I found out that I need to build a lot of reusable components that will be shared across multiple scaffolders and templates.

I know I can build a class library and register it in the GAC to make it accessible to the powershell scripts and T4 templates, but in a team environment, that is not always possible. I'd prefer to check-in the reusable components to source control and make them accessible somehow.

One approach I took was to split the T4 templates into multiple files and `include` all of them into the master template.

```
<#@ include file="Extensions.cs.t4" #>
```

However, if I define a class in any one of the templates, the class becomes a nested class and therefore can not be static (for example).

Is there a way to build re-usable classes, methods, extensions and make them accessible to custom scaffolders without installing them to the GAC? The T4Scaffolding package has a number of [utility functions accessible in the custom scaffolder](http://mvcscaffolding.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4Scaffolding%27s%20cmdlets%20for%20use%20in%20custom%20scaffolders&referringTitle=Documentation). How did they do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9084847/99373). I have to build an assembly with all my shared code. Then, in the Powershell script, I just have to:

```
import-module "d:\path\to\assembly.dll"
```

Hope that helps someone. And if anyone has a better idea, please share.