# How can I t4 scaffold from powershell.exe using Jenkins for nightlybuild

Tags: templates, jenkins, t4, using

We use our .net project fully based on t4Scaffold Template. So we have to automate this. Actually we tried to execute powershell command but scaffolding commands not working.
  just like
      "The term 'T4Scaffolding' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program"

we got a help form this following link:
  [How can I t4 scaffold from powershell.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049244/how-can-i-t4-scaffold-from-powershell-exe)

but it is not working, Our requirement is to automate t4Scaffold and generated files move to another folder using jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

We have a BAT file that executes our T4 generation.
The text transform is a tool that comes with Visual Studio (we commited it into our build tools folder)

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET TextTransform="%~dp0..\Build\tools\TextTransform\TextTransform.exe"
%TextTransform% "YourFile.tt" -out "YourFile.cs"
echo Transformation Complete
```

The actual location of the *TextTransform.exe* on your machine will be in a folder under 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\TextTemplating\`

Comment: error: Failed to load base class 'DynamicTransform' from which Trasformation class inherits.